# SQL Server - Is there a way to enforce a maximum lock hold timeout?

Tags: c#, sql-server

There appears to be a an extremely rare instance of the following in our application:

1. Code does large read, escalating to a table lock
2. Worker performing large read is poorly killed and ends up in a partial / stalled state whilst holding the table lock
3. The lock is not released by SQL server until the stalled process is fully killed

It's not clear what is causing Step 2, and it's likely to be hard to fix.

What I can't find is any way to prevent SQL server allowing any process to hold a lock for a long period of time. Hence my question, can you enforce a maximum lock timeout on SQL Server?

This would mean we could ensure no lock is held for longer than, say, 15 seconds - and if this did happen, we could act upon it on a case by case basis.

**Edit for additional info:**

All queries are cleaned up in the normal case (with a using block). This is a case of an extremely rare instance of normally 100% working and valid line of code being erratically terminated such that it ends up in a partial state holding the lock. This itself is happening at a lower level (Linq to sql / entity framework / connection pooling).

As such - yes, we can avoid all table locks as a rule, but that is hard to enforce. We can try to find the bug causing the stalled process, but that is potentially even harder. Hence I thought if there was a way to enforce the prevention of long table locks, this would actually be preferable. [@Dan Guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman) kindly shared that he does not think this is possible. Given this is a theoretical desired setting, if you had a query that absolutely needed to run longer, you could override this setting ([@jesús lópez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4540020/jes%C3%BAs-l%C3%B3pez))

Comment: Although you can control how long SQL Server waits for a lock, I'm not aware of a way to enforce how long it's held.

Comment: What if you have a transaction that takes longer than 15 seconds?

Comment: You should probably specify a command timeout, not just a lock timeout. Or use snapshot isolation

Comment: BTW if you have a large read (eg millions of rows), 15 seconds is a *really* low timeout.

Comment: What does the *other* process do? Is it a reporting query? An ETL job? How about fixing *it*? SQL Server can't really know that the process forgot to close the connection. If that process is written in C# it's **very** easy to avoid leaked connections by creating connections inside a `using` block

Comment: BTW SO is the proper place to ask how to fix the *process*. dba.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask how to handle misbehaving clients from SQL Server's side. Perhaps you could do something with resource governor?

Comment: @dazbradbury Unless you intend to fix the client, this should be closed and moved to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can force ROWLOCKS instead of a table lock using the WITH(ROWLOCK) hint but depending on the number of rows, it may be overly memory intensive.

Comment: @dazbradbury you need to put the *connection* in the using block, not the command. There's no way that a `using` block won't close the **connection**. `using` ensures that `Dispose()` is called even when exceptions that *can't* be caught by `catch`. If the connection and transaction remain open it means something *prevented* the exception from bubbling up. Are you using global connections or connections stored in fields? A connection should be created and opened right before it's used and closed immediatelly. Connection pooling ensures there's no cost to this

Comment: @dazbradbury anyway, to avoid *blocking* use snapshot isolation for the reads. It's easier than searching for hypothetical server fixes to client bugs. Ensure there are no catch blocks *inside* the using block or that you don't reuse the same transaction all over the place. Add *command timeouts* so there are no runaway queries. Add logging so you know what threw and when, or at least what the last operation was. Worst case, take a memory dump of the process and open it in Visual Studio to see what's going on while the process is stalled.

Comment: @dazbradbury [Collecting Crash Dumps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cobold/2010/03/01/collecting-crash-dumps/) shows how to create a crash dump from a failing process. You can [open a crash dump in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx) and check the current execution locations, call stacks etc as if you were debugging the application. The source code, and pdbs though have to be the same as the deployed application.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting XACT_ABORT ON, either in the worker code or by checking the default in the server connection properties. It will rollback transactions that might be holding the locks. Depending on how your code is structured, it could affect the process if error handling is written convolutedly, so please be aware.

Comment: If the client process is stalled, I don't think `XACT_ABORT ON` will help since that's not an error on the server side.

Comment: @DanGuzman If a connection still holds a lock after erroring due to, most likely timing out at the number of seconds determined by the client, XACT_ABORT on the client will roll it back. The Server Connections Xact Abort setting defaults the setting for the connection, not the server.

Comment: @cloudsafe if the *client* timed out, the OP wouldn't need to ask the question. In any case `XACT_ABORT` means that the transaction will be aborted if the *server* raises an error: `Specifies whether SQL Server automatically rolls back the current transaction when a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The timeout on the client connection could be error-handled, still leaving the transaction open. By client, I am referring to the client connection.

Comment: @cloudsafe, a XACT_ABORT ON will rollback an explicit tran after the client sends a cancel request following a query timeout or when an error occurs on the server. But this looks to be a SELECT query, likely without an explicit transaction, and the application has simply stalled processing the large result set. SQL Server will hold the locks in that case regardless of the XACT_ABORT setting.

Comment: @DanGuzman The OP says that the worker is holding a lock, so I think the OP identified the SPID when investigating. In order to work through this, I would try changing the XACT_ABORT default and retry, checking the lock again with sp_who2. -- MInd you, I am reading the OP as saying there are 2 threads (1. and 2.). Maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @cloudsafe the query didn't throw any errors so XACT_ABORT has nothing to abort.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP says the query was killed. That must have produced an error.

Comment: @cloudsafe if it had, the transaction would have aborted anyway, whether implicit or explicit. The OP wrote `Worker performing large read is poorly killed`. *On the other hand* if the *query* itself uses `TRY_CATCH` the error would be hidden.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos An explicit transaction would still be open if the error handling did not commit or roll back and there is connection pooling.